# Duplicate values MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this records in a N-N relation:

| UserId | DomicilioId | FechaCambio | Observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2928BBF3-D55B-41D0-9128-95AD491CC151 | 6 | 2021-09-27 08:13:39 |  |
| 2928BBF3-D55B-41D0-9128-95AD491CC151 | 5 | 2021-09-24 09:34:20 | Mudanza |
| 097E8524-3784-4F63-A921-1B174AB102B4 | 4 | 2021-09-22 11:11:46 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |
| EF1B8D25-0C44-4CC1-B5A9-D6D6ECF2831F | 3 | 2021-09-21 11:54:48 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |
| 2928BBF3-D55B-41D0-9128-95AD491CC151 | 2 | 2021-09-18 19:46:14 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |
| C7EE638E-1267-4511-922D-B1311D0CA32F | 1 | 2021-09-17 22:11:20 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |

I need this expected output:

| UserId | DomicilioId | FechaCambio | Observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2928BBF3-D55B-41D0-9128-95AD491CC151 | 6 | 2021-09-27 08:13:39 |  |
| 097E8524-3784-4F63-A921-1B174AB102B4 | 4 | 2021-09-22 11:11:46 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |
| EF1B8D25-0C44-4CC1-B5A9-D6D6ECF2831F | 3 | 2021-09-21 11:54:48 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |
| C7EE638E-1267-4511-922D-B1311D0CA32F | 1 | 2021-09-17 22:11:20 | Primer Domicilio del abonado |

Basically I need to remove the duplicate rows where UserId is equal. I have tried using DISTINCT and GROUP BY but none of them worked so far.

Comment: which one to keep from two duplicates of each other?

Comment: *I have this records in a N-N relation:* And what is "N-N related" in your data? *I need to remove the duplicate rows where UserId is equal.* What row must be saved? what is precise criteria?

Comment: These records are not duplicates, just record multiple transaction per user id. Based on the logic derived from the two sample tables, you want to keep the latest version of records per user.

Comment: I need to bring all the records at the same time, not with user id